# Implement call back in C#

Tags: c#

New to C# and trying to figure out how to do a call back.  (if this is indeed a callback)

I have a number of calls in the format ..

```
        connector.Subscribe(data1, data2, (element, value) =>
        {
            Log($"{element.Name}: {value}");
        });
```

and I would like to have them all use the same function instead of adding the code to each
For example

```
    public void somefunction(element, value)
    {
        Log($"{element.Name}: {value}");
    }

    connector.Subscribe(data1, data2, somefunction);
```

Honestly, I have no idea where to start so any help is appreciated

Comment: This is possible, but first let me ask: have you looked into [C# events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/)? I think callbacks are an anti-pattern

Comment: It's not an antipattern unless you can explain why it is not an antipattern.

Comment: @RobertHarvey perhaps I'm using the term "anti-pattern" too loosely, but it seems to me the OP is trying to implement the observer pattern. Using callbacks you need to manage the subscribers yourself, which the language in this case can handle for you for free.

Answer (score 8):

Declare a delegate with a signature matching the function's signature. E.g.:

```
public delegate void MyCallback(string name, int value);
```

Then declare `Subscribe` as

```
public void Subscribe(object data1, object data2, MyCallback myCallback)
{
}
```

Then you can do what you asked for:

```
connector.Subscribe(data1, data2, somefunction);
```

Note that `somefunction` must be written without the parameter braces here.

---

Another way to solve the problem is to declare an appropriate interface. E.g. an `ILogger` interface. Instead of passing a logger function, you would pass a logger object.

This has advantages:

- You can inject a logger. See [Dependency injection (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).
- You can configure the logger to be used in a central place by using an [IoC Container (TutorialsTeacher)](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/ioc/ioc-container).
- You can create a wrapper object implementing `ILogger` that itself accepts a list of `ILogger` objects in a constructor. E.g. you could pass it a console logger and a file logger. The call sites don't need to know that you want everything to be logged twice.
- You can use a dummy logger doing nothing if you don't want to log (again without changing the call sites).

In other words. An interface is more flexible than a delegate.

Comment: Instead of declaring your own delegate (which is perfectly fine, of course), you could also use the [`Action<T1, T2>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-2) delegate here: `public void Subscribe(object data1, object data2, Action<string, int> myCallback)`.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. The advantage of a delegate is that you can give it a speaking name (hopefully a better one than `MyCallback` as in my example) and you can also name the parameters.

Comment: I agree that "custom" delegates are indeed somewhat better regarding self-documenting code. But it might also be worth mentioning that the names of the parameters do not need to match, of course; only the types and the order of the parameters need to match. For a beginning programmer, that might perhaps be somewhat confusing.